# How can I create the effect of a background partially disappearing when I hover with the pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm attempting to create a scenario where I have two divs, and when hovered over, the background of one div should partially disappear, resembling a small circle around the pointer.

```
<div className='bg-img1 h-32 w-32 bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center' id='div1'>
  <div className='bg-img2 h-32 w-32 bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center' id='div2'></div>
</div>
```

The idea is that when hovering over div1, the background should fade away in a circular pattern around the pointer, and this effect should follow the movement of the pointer. Is there a way to achieve this?

PostData: I'm using React JS and TailWind Css.

I've attempted to search for solutions related to making a background react to the pointer in React, but the results mostly provided information on creating a circle that follows the pointer rather than achieving the specific effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're aiming to uncover the background of `div1` as we hover the cursor over `div2`.

The provided code utilizes the `.partial-disappear` class, masking the background with variable `--x` and `--y`, enabling this functionality

```js
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

div2.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const y = e.clientY - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  div1.style.setProperty('--x', `${x}px`);
  div1.style.setProperty('--y', `${y}px`);
  div2.classList.add('partial-disappear');
});

div2.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  div2.classList.remove('partial-disappear');
});
```

```css
/* Set height and bg-size */
#div1,#div2 {
height:400px;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
}

/* Set background */
#div1 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529619768328-e37af76c6fe5?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D');
}

#div2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548850174-70a1cf2c5f09?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8N3x8bmlnaHQlMjBjaXR5fGVufDB8fDB8fHww');
}

 /* Partially hide the background of div2. Set 'transparent' and 'black' value accordig to your requirement */
.partial-disappear {
  mask: radial-gradient(circle at var(--x) var(--y), transparent 70px, black 120px);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle at var(--x) var(--y), transparent 70px, black 120px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img1 h-32 w-32 bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center" id="div1">
  <div class="bg-img2 h-32 w-32 bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```